# Failing to continually save and update a .CSV file after a period of time

Tags: python, csv, collections, export-to-csv

I have a written a small program that reads values from two pieces of equipment every minuet and then saves it to a .csv file. I wanted the file to be updated and saved after every collection of every point so that if pc crashes, or other problem occurs no data loss occurs. To do that I open the file (ab mode), use write row  and the close the file in a loop. The time between collections is about 1 minuet. This works quiet well, but the problem is after 5-6 hours of data collection, it stops saving to .csv file, and does not bring up any errors, the code continues to run with graph being update like nothing happened, but opening the .csv file reveals that data is lost. I would like to know if there is something wrong with the code I am using. I should also not I am running a subprocess from this that does live plotting, but I do not think it would cause an issue... I added those code lines as well.

```
##Initial file declaration and header
with open(filename,'wb') as wdata:
     savefile=csv.writer(wdata,dialect='excel')
     savefile.writerow(['System time','Time from Start(s)','Weight(g)','uS/cm','uS','Measured degC','%/C','Ideal degC','/cm'])

##Open Plotting Subprocess
 draw=subprocess.Popen('TriPlot.py',shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
##data collection loop
while True:
   Collect Data x and y
   Waits for data about 60 seconds, no sleep or pause commoand used, pyserial inteface is used.
   ## Send Data to subprocess 
   draw.stdin.write('%d\n' % tnow)
   draw.stdin.write('%d\n' % s_w)
   draw.stdin.write('%d\n' % tnow)
   draw.stdin.write('%d\n' % float(s_c[5]))

   ##Saving data Section 
   wdata=open(filename,'ab')
   savefile=csv.writer(wdata,dialect='excel')
   savefile.writerow([tcurrent,tnow,s_w,s_c[5],s_c[7],s_c[9],s_c[11],s_c[13],s_c[15]])
   wdata.close()
```

P.S This code uses the following packages for code not shown.  pyserial, csv, os, subprocess,Tkinter, string, numpy, time and wx.

Comment: you could open filename once and just call `wdata.flush()` at the end of the loop (you could add `os.fsync(wdata)` it might help in rare cases)

Comment: could you reproduce it if you just write dummy data ~1000 times?

Comment: J.F I will try reproducing writing a long data file. For the .flush() I would move the wdata=open and savefile=csv.writer out of the loop and just call savefile.writerow() followed wdata.flush() in the loop?

Comment: yes, `.writerow(); .flush()`

Comment: Have you thought about using the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) library? It'd be easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the subprocess is to blame, I was able to replicate the issue. It seems that after while calling draw.stdin.write('%d\n' % tnow) stop the code. Removign it seems to fix the issue. Thanks all.

Comment: @user1957292: [edit] your question to include the info about `draw.stdin.write`

Answer (score 1):

If `draw.stdin.write()` blocks it probably means that you are not consuming `draw.stdout` in a timely manner. The docs warn about the dead-lock due to the full OS pipe buffer.

If you don't need the output you could set `stdout=devnull` where `devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')` otherwise there are several approaches to read the output without blocking your code: threads, select, `tempfile.TemoraryFile`.